# REST API - How to convert a property from int/string to string when model binding?

Tags: c#, json, json.net, asp.net-core-3.1, model-binding

In my API, I created a client using Refit to call a third party API. The problem is that the third party API is returning inconsistent data. It returns city names and postcodes but sometimes these are int or strings :

```
{
"input": "Pa",
"cities": [
    {
        "code": "09100",
        "city": "PAMIERS"
    },
    {
        "code": "09130",
        "city": "PAILHES"
    },
    {
        "code": 10100,
        "city": "PARS LES ROMILLY"
    },
    {
        "code": 10160,
        "city": "PAISY COSDON"
    },
    {
        "code": 10210,
        "city": "PARGUES"
    }
]
}
```

So I created this route :

```
public async Task<IActionResult> SearchCity([FromForm] CitySearch data)
{
    var api = RestService.For<ICityAPI>("https://vicopo.selfbuild.fr");
    try
    {
        var search = await api.SearchCityListAsync(data.search);
        return Ok(search);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status502BadGateway, ex);
    }
}
```

Who uses this client :

```
public interface ICityAPI
{
    [Get("/search/{search}")]
    Task<CityList> SearchCityListAsync(string search);
}
```

To finally bind the received Json to this model :

```
public class CityList
{
    [JsonProperty("cities")]
    public List<City> Cities { get; set; }
}

public class City
{
    [JsonProperty("city")]
    public string city { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("code")]
    public string code { get; set; }
}
```

How can I bind this Json to my model when it is not constant?

Comment: A "quick and dirty" way would be to change the property to `object`, for example: `public object code { get; set; }`. Otherwise you'll have to create a custom JSON converter, and even then, what would be the final type? Maybe leading zeros aren't important and you could just drop them and store as `int`; But, maybe not -- then you'd just store everything as `string`.

Comment: Do you know what JSON serializer you are using?  The fact that you have annotated your model with `[JsonProperty]` suggests you are using Json.NET, and with Json.NET it just works.  The int values are automatically deserialized as strings as long as you declare `public string code`.  See https://dotnetfiddle.net/4M9gaw.  So, what is your problem exactly? Can you share a [mcve]?

Comment: Incidentally the reason that `"09130"` must be a string is that the JSON standard does not allow for leading zeros in an integer literal (to avoid confusion with JavaScript Octal literals I believe).